# Некоректно работает функция hover

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пытался прикрепить на свой сайт этот плагин [`BookBlock`](http://www.coolwebmasters.com/codes-and-scripts/3198-bookblock-a-content-flip-plugin.html) ([`demo`](http://tympanus.net/Development/BookBlock/)), но с некоторыми изменениями. А именно. Хотел чтобы страницы листались при наведении на блок с изображениями. При наведении вперед ну и при отводе курсора соответственно назад. Столкнулся с двумя проблемами:

1. Некорректно работает функция `hover`. При наведении все срабатывает и изображение листается вперед, но при отводе курсора ничего не происходит.
2. Как сделать, что бы функция сработала один раз?! То есть если курсор наведен на изображение, то оно перелистывается один раз и останавливается.

   ```
   var Page = (function () {

       var config = {
               $bookBlock: $('#bb-bookblock'),
               $navNext: $('#bb-nav-next'),
               $navPrev: $('#bb-nav-prev'),
           },
           init = function () {
               config.$bookBlock.bookblock({
                   speed: 800,
                   shadowSides: 0.8,
                   shadowFlip: 0.7
               });
               initEvents();
           },
           initEvents = function () {

               var $slides = config.$bookBlock.children();
           };

       $(".bb-item").hover(
           function () {
               config.$bookBlock.bookblock('next');

           },
           function () {
               config.$bookBlock.bookblock('prev');

           }
       );
       return {
           init: init
       };
   })();
   ```

Вот код html:

```
<div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock bb-vertical">
    <div class="bb-item">
        <a href="/">
            <img src="img/1.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="bb-item">
        <a href="/">
            <img src="img/2.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

То есть эффект повешен на bb-bookblock. Он не меняется

Comment: думаю проблема в том, что при листании меняется блок под курсором, вот оно и действует как попало, оберните вашу картику в еще один блок, на него и вешайте hover, в обработчиках hover, проверяйте что `(event.target===this)` или как там...

Comment: Написал код html + Заметил следующее. Использовал две библиотеки разных версий. Но не могу оставить одну конкретную. Один скрипт работает только на 1.3.2. Другой на 1.9.1. Суть не меняется. При любой библиотеке hover так и не работает как нужно

Comment: @HoPkInS вы комментарий прочитали ? По поводу версий - если 1.3.2 - версия jQuery, то надо однозначно избавляться от нее.

Comment: не   on mouseenter,mouseleave?

Comment: @eicto. Прочел я комментарий. Зачем мне оборачивать картинку еще в один див?! Они опять будут одинаковые эти два дива. Какой смысл? в обработчиках я ничего "такого" не нашел. Как избавится о версии 1.3.2. Если один скрипт только с этой версией и работает. Больше не с какой

Comment: ну если див не меняется, то можно не оборачивать, главное чтобы блок на который указан hover  не менялся по ходу пьесы. насчет 1.3.2 - это очень древняя версия jQuery, я не знаю что там у вас без нее не работает, наверное такой-же древний скрипт, могу только посочувствовать.

Comment: @eicto.Я и не оборачивал. Но hover не работает как положено!. Там плагин Cycle на ней работает. Может есть аналог этого плагина?!

Comment: ну на главной плагин cycle же написано черным по желтому

Check out [Cycle2](https://github.com/malsup/cycle2), the latest in the Cycle line of slideshows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение следующее. Поставил библиотеку 2.1.1. + migrate-1.2.1.min.js,немного подправил сам файл cycle.js, ну и hover в bookblock заменил на mouseover и mouseout